# New in Java getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have declared:

```
Discursiva[] questoesDiscursivas = new Discursiva[10];
```

Which is:

```
public class Discursiva extends Questao{
    private String criteriosCorrecao;
}
```

And Questao is:

```
public class Questao {
    private String pergunta;
    private double peso;
}
```

So I just did:

```
str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pergunta da Questao:");
questoesObjetivas[i].setPergunta(str);
```

And got java.lang.NullPointerException.

> I have read in oracle docs: Thrown when an application attempts to use
>   null in a case where an object is required. These include:
>
> ```
> Calling the instance method of a null object. 
> Accessing or modifying the field of a null object. 
> Taking the length of null as if it were an array. 
> Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array. 
> Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.
> ```

And I dont get why I am receiving `NullPointerException`.
Please dont bottomrate my question, Iam still learning Java, its like my first code in it and I would like your help, so please, how can I fix this?

Comment: Where are you initializing `questoesObjetivas`?

Comment: What is `questoesObjetivas`, how large is it and what is the value of `i` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: It would help to see all the code you are usign, or at least what's the code inside the setPergunta(String) function

Comment: If you looked at your code in a debugger you would be able to see that `questoesDiscursivas` is full of `null`s. This is because creating an array in Java doesn't implicitly fill the array with objects.

Comment: Both SLaks and AmitD, made me see my error, thanks all of you!

Comment: `Discursiva[] questoesDiscursivas = new Discursiva[10];` only initializes an array of 10 references, each reference pointing to nowhere! So you need to make each of them point to an actual object by something like `questoesObjetivas[i] = new Discursiva();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing this `questoesObjetivas[i]` first do this

```
 questoesObjetivas[i] = new Discursiva();
```

You will find a good article over [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Array only contains only references to objects if you declare Array of objects.Each value inside Array of object is initialized to null. So when you try to access it you will get `NullPointerException`

Because arrays are `covariant` `[if Sub is a subtype of Super, then the
array type Sub[] is a subtype of Super[] **Effective Java**]` in nature one should prefer `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Discursiva> questoesDiscursivas = new ArrayList<Discursiva>(10);
questoesDiscursivas.add(new Discursiva());
```

You can read more in **Effective Java** `Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays`

Comment: I just dont know why i have to declare it again, since i have done this:
Discursiva[] questoesDiscursivas = new Discursiva[10];

Comment: Might seem strange, but you just allocated the array. All values are set to null by default.

Comment: Well, thanks it worked, still needs 11 minutes to accept the awnser, but thanks

Comment: The array only contains pointers to potential instances of your object. What you did only creates the array with these pointers (initially pointing to null), but not the instances itself.

Comment: Added Link to article please go through it.

Answer (score 6):

Your array is full of `null`s.

You need to put a `new Discursiva()` in each slot of the array before you can use it.

Comment: +1 tell hime how to avoid `NPE` as he is new in java. He should never get `NPE`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the object in your array:

```
Discursiva[] questoesDiscursivas = new Discursiva[10];

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    questoesDiscursivas = new Discursiva();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have declared questoesObjetivas[i], but not initialised it.

Answer (score 0):

Upon creation, all of the elements of object arrays are initialized to `null`, so `questoesObjetivas[i].setPergunta(str)` will give a `NullPointerException` since the `i`th element of that array is indeed `null`. Try filling the array with instances of the `Discursiva` class.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the problem is in the two lines you gave :

`questoesObjetivas[i]` is null or `questoesObjetivas` is null

Answer (score 0):

you need to instanitate an Object so you  can put it inyour Array:

```
   questoesObjetivas[i] = new setPergunta(str);
```